# Condensing a repetitive operation

Tags: javascript

I have a repetitve javascript function, and the reason its repetitive is it because it sets variables a1, a2 and a3 at each stage.

How can I condense it?

```
DB_connect()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='LETTER' AND [COLOR]='RED' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+SQLDate(date1)+"# AND #"+SQLDate(date1_2)+"#"
a1 = Number(cn.Execute(SQL).Fields(0).Value)
cn.Close()


DB_connect()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='LETTER' AND [COLOR]='GREEN' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+SQLDate(date1)+"# AND #"+SQLDate(date1_2)+"#"
a2 = Number(cn.Execute(SQL).Fields(0).Value)
cn.Close()


DB_connect()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='LETTER' AND [COLOR]='BLUE' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+SQLDate(date1)+"# AND #"+SQLDate(date1_2)+"#"
a3 = Number(cn.Execute(SQL).Fields(0).Value)
cn.Close()
```

Comment: The answer is prepared statements. Though I have no idea what kind of database you're connecting, how you're using it, etc. Why are you interacting with a database from JavaScript anyway?

Comment: This code looks odd to me, but it's still valid JavaScript (albeit seemingly using global variables where it should be using local variables). And is that synchronous database access? As far as the question itself, since the only difference between the queries seems to be the color names, I might try storing the values in an object under property names equal to the color for the corresponding query: `var results = {}; var colorNames = ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE']; each(colorNames, function (colorName) { results[colorName] = getValue(colorName); });`. Put your query logic in `getValue`.